# How to become a Ph.D. in video game design?

Tags: game-design

The title says it all, I am wondering if it is possible and if so, how it would be possible, to become a Ph.D. in video game design. I'm quite sure you can become a Ph.D. in pretty much anything, but since video games are such an informal and relatively young sector, I thought I'd ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about why the letters Ph.D. are important to you? Most game designers I know have either no degree, or a bachelor's (quite often in a non-game field). The few I know with a master's degree got it primarily for the purpose of teaching. If we know what you ultimately want to do, we might be able to suggest routes there that don't necessarily require a Ph.D in game design.

Comment: I guess it's the same way you get a PhD in any other academic field. Maybe https://academia.stackexchange.com might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining a PhD in *game design* itself is likely impossible. Game design is an art rather than a science. PhD studies are conducted on scientific topics, with the goal of answering scientific questions, as to advance a field of technology.

It is however definitely possible to do PhD research on topics related to game design. Modern games draw from a lot of scientific fields, often sub-topics of computer sciences or information and communication technology. Some fields that are highly relevant in games include:

**Computer graphics** — The science generating a realistic rendering of virtual scenes on a display device. Important topics include: 2D rendering, 3D rendering, procedural generation, data visualization, lighting and shadows, materials, anti-aliasing, post-processing, virtual reality, augmented reality ...

**Artificial Intelligence** — The science of creating virtual agents that exhibit intelligent behavior. Important topics include: path finding, decision making, machine learning, computer vision, searching, probability theory ...

**Physics** — The science of studying physical phenomena, such as the behavior of matter reacting to various forces. Important topics include: rigid body dynamics, soft body dynamics, fluid dynamics, ballistics ...

**Software Engineering** — The science of studying software architectures, patterns, and best practices. Important topics include: game engine design, memory management, GPU programming, specialized data structures (octrees, scene graphs ...), specialized algorithms ...

**Signal processing** — The science of how signals can be modified through specific systems. Important topics include: frequency analysis, sound modelling, geometry processing and compression ...

**Psychology & Communication Sciences** — The science of studying social behavior, and how it is influences by various media. Important topics include: serious games (i.e. educational games), multimedia ...

I personally did PhD research on procedural generation, and got in touch with researchers of all the above topics. All of them had performed studies on the topic of games, in both smaller and greater degrees.

So in summary, pursuing a PhD in game itself is likely impossible as it is an art rather than a science. Game design is a very complex task however, and it draws from a plethora of scientific fields. It is very possible to perform research in one of those fields, and choose a topic relevant to games. As others have said though, a PhD is not per se a guarantee to be a good game designer.

Comment: Can't you do a PhD in photography? In painting? These fields are very much art.